# Storing coordinates in a nested list using loop

Tags: python, list

I am having the coordinates of a robot, I am taking the number of robots as
input and storing the coordinates in a list called locations. I want locations to store the coordinates of all robots.

Using a  loop I am appending a empty list inside locations and I am storing the coordinates into the sub-list.

```
locations = []

m = input("Number of robots: ")

for i in range(m)
    locations.append([])

    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
    z = z + 1
    locations[i].append(x)
    locations[i].append(y)
    locations[i].append(z) 
print(locations)
```

I expect the result to be locations`[(1,1,1),(2,2,2)....]`, but I am not able to get the output.

Comment: what happens when you try to run the code? Can you confirm if the code you've written here is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Why appending an empty list first and then putting content to it?

```py
locations = []
x = y = z = 0

m = input("Number of robots: ")

for i in range(m):
  x = x + 1
  y = y + 1
  z = z + 1

  locations.append([x, y, z])

print(locations)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
locations = []
m = input("Number of robots: ")
for i in range(1, m+1): # This starts from 1 and print till m(m+1 is to consider "m")
    locations.append((i,i,i)) # This will create your desired output.
print(locations)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
locations = []

m = input("Number of robots: ")

for i in range(int(m)):
    x += 1
    y += 1
    z += 1
    locations.append([x, y, z])

print(locations)
```

Comment: No, the input is not converted to integer, and there is a missing colon after the `for` line...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
locations = []
x = y = z = 0

m = input("Number of robots: ")

for i in range(m):
  x = x + 1
  y = y + 1
  z = z + 1

  locations.append((x, y, z))

print(locations)
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate input you can use [`isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal).

```
m = -1
while m < 0:
    inp = input("Number of robots: ")
    if inp.isdecimal():
        m = int(inp)
    else:
        print("Invalid input.")
```

To create new list with tuples I can recommend to use list comprehension with [sequence repetition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).

```
locations = [(i,) * 3 for i in range(1, m + 1)]
print(locations)
```

Output:

```
Number of robots: word
Invalid input.
Number of robots: 5
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4), (5, 5, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
locations = []

m = int(input("Number of robots: "))
x, y, z = 0, 0, 0
for i in range(m):
    x, y, z = x + 1, y + 1, z + 1
    locations.append([x, y, z])
print(locations)
```

There are a few mistakes in your code:

- a missing colon after the `for in in range`
- a missing conversion of the input to an integer.

Even better, you could use a simple [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
locations = [[i, i, i] for i in range(int(input("Number of robots: ")))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you've had a lot of answers already, but just wanted to go over your original code and look at what's going on:

```
locations = []

m = input("Number of robots: ")

# You're missing a colon here
# Also, since m was user input, it's actually of type string
# You could use the 'int' function around it to make it an integer
for i in range(int(m)):

    locations.append([])

    # x, y and z are not defined, though I'm assuming you've done this elsewhere
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
    z = z + 1
    locations[i].append(x)
    locations[i].append(y)
    locations[i].append(z)

print(locations)
```

With those change, the output I received was:
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]

As others have pointed out, there's no need to append an empty list, you could remove the empty list append line and replace the other append lines of code with something as simple as:

```
locations.append((x,y,z))
```

Your output is then the following, which I think was your original intention:
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3), (4, 4, 4)]